# Can flight data recorders be hacked?

Tags: flight-data-recorder, security, accident-investigation

In the event of a plane crash such as [MH17](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malaysia_Airlines_Flight_17), and the flight data recorders (FDR, a.k.a. "black boxes") are potentially in the "wrong hands", is it theoretically possible to:

1. open the FDR and close it again without leaving traces?
2. alter or selectively erase data of the FDR?

In other words, can an FDR professionally be tampered with as opposed to purely destroyed for the purpose of hindering an investigation?

Comment: Fortunately for MH17 case the CVR and FDR are not very important. There would be nothing unusual before the explosion and the explosion most likely stopped power and so the recording. Important proofs will be radar records observing the missile that USA officials already reported to have ([mentioned on AvHerald](http://avherald.com/h?article=47770f9d)), debris of the missile itself if the official investigators or OSCE observers manage to find any and traces on debris of the aircraft indicating the explosion happened outside.

Comment: I know it's conspiratorial, but what if the plane crashed due to malfunction and both sides are trying to use this unfortunate event as a pretext to other actions?

Comment: @jnovacho In that case the examination by investigators will have to find no fregments of anti-aircraft equipment and the remains of the fuselage will have to contain no signs of shrapnel or external damage where it cannot occur, e.g. if one of the engines disintegrated without external influence, the damage on the fuselage will indicate this by the way the debris or engine parts penetrated the structure. I am not sure if chemical traces would be on the fuselage. That's a question for the missile-experts.

Comment: Dont know if this is true of current commercial planes, but I saw a recent air disaster documentary that stated that even after removing power the recorders will carry on recording for a few seconds.

Comment: @SentryRaven: _Or_ they could just have someone "persuade" the investigators to go along with their version of events.

Answer (score 17):

Yes.  Black boxes aren't designed to be tamper-resistant.

The hard part is not the physical act of tampering with a black box, it's constructing a coherent false narrative of what happened during the time period.  The FDR records 80+ channels of data, which an investigator can correlate against each other, against data in the [quick access recorder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quick_access_recorder), against [ACARS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACARS) reports, and against the physical condition of the airplane itself.

For example, say you want to "prove" that an airplane's engines were shut down mid-flight, leading to a crash.  You could modify the FDR's record to show a throttle setting of "closed" and an engine RPM of 0, but the exhaust temperature would still be high, the fuel tank levels would still be dropping, and analysis of damage to the turbine blades would show a mix of axial and circumferential bending around the entire circumference of the blade disk, rather than the pure axial bending on a single side that would be expected if the engines had stopped spinning.

Comment: Do you know if there is at least a seal? Has there ever been a reported case where someone has tried to tamper with the FDR?

Comment: In the case of MH17, I doubt the FDR would show much of anything that someone would want to hack, (other than possibly its exact position on one side of a border).  It likely showed everything was fine up until the moment of catastrophic failure of multiple systems, all at once.

Comment: What would stop someone from reflying a crashed flight in another plane and swapping out the FDRs? Not referring to MH17.

Comment: @DannyBeckett: The information recorded by the second FDR wouldn't match the information recorded by external systems such as ATC. It would be extraordinarily difficult to replicate *all* the conditions of the original flight.

Comment: Note, that neither recorder is going to contain anything proving shot-down anyway as they would most likely just abruptly stop. Radar records observing the missile (that USA already officially reported to have) and analysis of the debris can prove a shot-down without the recorders.

Comment: But Shirley a device designed to withstand hundreds of G shock, hundreds of degrees fires and submersion in hundreds of meters of water, should to a certain extent be more than a little difficult to disassemble, let alone reassemble.

Comment: I see what you did there.

Comment: A crash in Peru(?) had its FDR taken by looters- they recovered the box by giving  a reward but the data was too damaged partly by the looter to be useful.